# Personalisation Overview Preview is loading empty image

Tags: personalization, content-testing

I am using Sitecore 9.2 in Azure environment. I see in Azure the Personalization Overview preview is empty which means it does not render page.
There is no firewall setting configured. I checked all settings in
**Sitecore.ContetentTesting.config** file are fine.
In network requests under developer tool I see it keeps hitting **TryFinishGetThumbnails** and then gets timeout after sometime.
Can somebody suggest what can be missing.

[image]